# How to open already installed app on iPhone in automated way w/o ios-deploy

Tags: ios, xcode, command-line, xcodebuild, iosdeployment

I am stuck at a point, please help me someone.

I have an .ipa and i am installing it on my iPhone via iOS-Deploy, now i want to open that application in an automated fashion. How can i do that ??
I am not using iOS-Deploy further to open the application because then i won't be able to accept the alerts that come i.e Contacts, Microphone, Camera etc. This is the main reason i want to use something like Apple's XCUITest .. **Can someone please tell me how do i open this already installed application.**

I used below command for my project but this would build the application - which i don't want

```
xcodebuild -project name.xcodeproj -scheme nameUITests -configuration Debug test -sdk iphonesimulator -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 5' -only-testing:nameUITests/nameUITests
```

Can someone please help me, or guide me how to achieve my goal..
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Why is nobody taking interest replying to this question.. I really hope it's not that difficult.

Comment: Can you describe in details what do you want to achieve? Running the UI test will always build and install a fresh copy of the application. Why it's not an option for you?

Comment: @MichałMyśliwiec - Thanks atleast for taking interest, because i have an .ipa to test,  i don't want to build application as it would violate my CI purpose. I am not exactly doing UI Automation but want to test an SDK(integrated in my app) now i get all sorts of security popups(camera, microphone,contacts etc), to dismiss those i need to use something. Those can't just go away!!